# mySQL reference correlation in a subquery with join

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on a small social network service.
Very classically, I have 3 tables :
- table **"circles_users"** : all users that belong to the same "circle"
- table **"friends"** : friendship relation between users
- table **"checkin"** : is a user "checkin" somewhere or not

Here the structure of the database : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/27888/1

I would like to ask my database to give me :
all users from a specific "circle" with **for each of them :**
- the number of friends this user has in common with **user id = 3**
- if this user is checkin or not

Here what I'm trying to do :

```
SELECT a.uid, 
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM (SELECT IF (uid1 = 3, uid2, uid1) AS cf FROM friends WHERE (friends.uid1 = 3 OR friends.uid2 = 3 )) as b 
    JOIN friends ON ((friends.uid1 = b.cf AND friends.uid2 = a.uid) OR (friends.uid1 = a.uid AND friends.uid2 = b.cf))
) as common_friends, 
checkin.status as checkin_status 
FROM 
(SELECT circles_users.uid FROM circles_users WHERE circles_users.circlename = 'circle_A') as a
LEFT JOIN checkin ON checkin.uid = a.uid
```

I get this error message : **Unknown column 'a.uid' in 'on clause'**
It has been now 2 days that I'm trying to fix this unsuccessfully.

It seems that it is not possible to reference correlation name in my subquery.
For instance, if I replace **a.uid** in the subquery by a specific uid (for instance let's say '4'), I don't get any error. But of course, the result is false...

Is there someone who could help me ?
That would be very nice :)

---

**OTHER OPTION TO FOLLOW ?**

Another option would be to pass the "common_friends" subquery as a join.
I tried to do something like this :

```
SELECT a.uid, 
c.cnt as common_friends, 
checkin.status as checkin_status 
FROM 
(SELECT circles_users.uid as uid FROM circles_users WHERE circles_users.circlename = 'circle_A') as a
LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) as cnt 
        FROM (SELECT IF (uid1 = 3, uid2, uid1) AS cf FROM friends WHERE (friends.uid1 = 3 OR friends.uid2 = 3 )) as b 
        JOIN friends ON ((friends.uid1 = b.cf AND friends.uid2 = a.uid) OR (friends.uid1 = a.uid AND friends.uid2 = b.cf))
    ) as c ON 1=1 
LEFT JOIN checkin ON checkin.uid = a.uid
```

But again : I get this error message : **Unknown column 'a.uid' in 'on clause'**
Anyway, do you think this version would be easier to handle and would open new possibilities to resolve my problem ?

---

**If you want to play with my queries : (thanks to @zundarz)**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/27888/1

Comment: Have you tried not using an alias for a, and just doing circles_users.uid?

Comment: @Sewder : yes. I get same error : Unknown column 'group_users.uid' in 'on clause'

Comment: Or perhaps, assign an alias to circles_user.uid as in  `circles_user.uid as uid`

Comment: @zundarz : I tried. May be I'm not doing it right, but it does not seem to work. I still get Unknown column 'uid' in 'on clause'

Comment: SELECT a.uid, 
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM (SELECT IF (uid1 = 3, uid2, uid1) AS cf FROM friends WHERE (friends.uid1 = 3 OR friends.uid2 = 3 )) as b 
    JOIN friends ON ((friends.uid1 = b.cf AND friends.uid2 = a.uid) OR (friends.uid1 = a.uid AND friends.uid2 = b.cf))
) as common_friends, 
checkin.status 
FROM circles_users a
LEFT JOIN checkin ON (checkin.uid = a.uid AND checkin.status = "on")
WHERE a.circlename = 'mycirclename'

Comment: @Eric.K.Yung : thanks for the proposition ! But unfortunately not working. Still have : Unknown column 'a.uid' in 'on clause'

Comment: Take a look at this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d74c46/2. Is it close to your schema?

Comment: @zundarz : thank you for that ! I didn't know sqlfiddle. Very convenient. Your schema is very close from mine. I've made few corrections : sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d74c46/2

Comment: My changes on sqlfiddle have not be saved : I paste the schema directly above...

Comment: Each iteration of sqlfiddle gets a new url usually by autoincrement last digits. Next question. what do you want for output?

Comment: Something like the following fields : uid, common_friends, checkin_status. Does it answer your question ?

Comment: Getting closer: given the data you've presented. what do you want for results? e.g. 4 rows or 3 rows, which userids,common_friends and checkin_status? Once I know what rows you want, I can understand your query better.

Comment: 4 rows with fields (uid / common_friends / checkin_status) and following values : (1, 2, on), (3, 3, on), (4, 2, off), (6, 2, on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrote a query based on the info you give and what you are looking for.

```
SELECT cu.uid, COUNT(f.uid1) common_friends, c.status
FROM circles_users cu
LEFT JOIN friends f
    ON (f.uid1 = cu.uid OR f.uid2 = cu.uid)
   AND f.status = "on"
   AND IF (f.uid1 = cu.uid, f.uid2, f.uid1) IN (
      SELECT IF (uid1 = 3, uid2, uid1)
      FROM friends
      WHERE status = "on"
        AND (friends.uid1 = 3 OR friends.uid2 = 3)
   )
LEFT JOIN checkin c
    ON c.uid = cu.uid AND c.status = "on"
WHERE cu.circlename = "circle_A"
GROUP BY cu.uid
```

Example [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0147b/1)

Comment: What are you getting? Error? Wrong results? What is your table-structure?

Comment: COUNT(f.*) seems to raise an error. If I hide it, the query is executed but very slow (over 10s)

Comment: here is the table-structure as requested :  [link]http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/27888/1

Comment: I've updated my answer with 2 possible queries. The 2nd of which omits user 3 from the results and looks at `friends.status` which I think you'd want.

Comment: thank you so much ! It is exactly what I was looking for. I'm going to read this query carefully to understand how you did it and try to get better at SQL. Thanks again.

Comment: Reading my own query again, it occurs to me that if a user IS in "circle_A" but has NO mutual friends with user 3, then they are omitted from the results in stead of just having the result 0, so I updated the result once again. I also read your comments underneath the question, you **DO** want the user 3 itself in there.

Comment: exactly, thanks for the update ! Actually, I studied yesterday your query and adapted it to match my real query which was more complicated than my simplified example above. I applied your query's schema to my complex query and I succeeded to make a working one that matches my needs. Well done !